# What is the use of fast diodes vs rectifier diodes?

Tags: diodes, ac

I read

https://new.abb.com/semiconductors/Diodes/fast-recovery-diodes

And it makes fast recovery diodes sound like it’s only for converting dc to ac while rectifier diodes are for converting ac to dc. At the same time it sounds like fast diodes are only for frequencies that are too fast for the rectifier diode. Which one is it?

Comment: DC-DC converter circuits like boost converters often have a high switching frequently (i.e. 1.5MHz). Depending on what frequently you want, a Schottcky diode would probably be better since the turn on time is faster, so your output voltage won't collapse due to the diode not being able to keep up.

Comment: I think the only reason to use rectifier diodes instead of fast diodes is cost unless you can't find a fast diode with high enough current, voltage or low enough leakage. Otherwise you can use fast diodes everywhere rectifier diodes would work.

Comment: *fast recovery diodes sound like it’s only for converting dc to ac* You're misreading, it says: *Fast diodes...are **companion devices** to switches in DC to AC conversion.* They are used as "flyback" diodes when using a switching transistor that is switching a current through an inductor or transformer.

Answer (score 3):

Diodes conduct some time also to the reverse direction when the diode at first was conducting to the forward direction and the voltage is reversed.

Fast recovery diodes are optimized for fast turning off when the voltage is turned from forward to reversed. Its needed in switch mode power supplies because generally the time when a diode conducts to the wrong direction cause losses. The same is true in circuits which convert DC to AC.

Rectification diodes which are used at 50...50Hz are not optimized for fast recovery, but for low losses in forward state. The voltage drop for forward current has been tried to be kept as low as possible. The recovery time can be several microseconds, but that's not catastrophic with 50...60Hz sinusoidal voltages. The unwanted reverse conduction happens sparsely when compared to SMPS which has 1000 times higher frequency and the sinusoidal voltage grows slowly when compared to pulses in SMPS.

If you put say a 1N4001 to the flyback pulse circuit in SMPS instead of a recommended fast recovery diode you can see radical increase of losses. Input current rises and parts run hotter because the reverse conduction time means a short circuit.

In radio circuits there's one more use for fast recovery diodes. The ending of the reverse direction current is possible to be made so abrupt that with properly designed resonant filters one can extract higher frequency sinewave (=a harmonic) with remarkably high efficiency. The idea is used commonly in microwave frequency multipliers.

Answer (score 2):

Their point is that rectifier diodes are fast enough for anything that comes out of the wall plug (or even the bulkhead in an aircraft) since those frequencies are typically 50, 60 or 400Hz (or thereabouts).

Higher frequencies are usually created by taking DC (either from a DC source or from a mains-frequency rectifier and filter) and chopping it up with a switch. Afterwards you often want to go back to DC but now  you need to deal with the chopped up high frequency power, so hence the need for a fast-recovery diode.

Those "high" frequencies might be anything from a few kHz to a few MHz.